# Find specific a $a$ and $b$ such that limit is $3$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find such $a$ and $b$ that $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(\sqrt{x^{2}+3x} + \sqrt{x^{2}-2x} + ax +b)=3$$
I'm first year undergrauate. And I got stuck in the very begining

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: This is the kind of question where *what you know, what you've studied thus far* etc can make or break your success in getting an answer at the level you need.  voting to close as (off-topic): Missing context.

Comment: Do you understand the answers given? (e.g. binomial expansion?, or what $\mathcal O(x^{-1}$ means? indeterminate forms? If you haven't yet, no problem) because the answerers may be forgetting how to work with only the tools available in a freshman, first semester calculus course.

Comment: I don't understand why we can use this expansion when x tends to infinity

Answer (score 3):

Limits of this kind are best treated with the substitution $x=1/t$, where we can assume $t>0$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}
\frac{\sqrt{1+3t}+\sqrt{1-2t}+a+bt}{t}
$$
In order for the limit to be finite, we need $a=-2$ (or it wouldn't be an indeterminate form). Then, apply the definition of derivative to the function
$$
f(t)=\sqrt{1+3t}+\sqrt{1-2t}+bt
$$
so that $f'(0)=3$.

Answer (score 2):

If you take the binomial expansion out a few terms...

$$\sqrt{x^2+3x}=x+\frac32+\mathcal O(x^{-1})\\\sqrt{x^2-2x}=x-1+\mathcal O(x^{-1})$$

So that

$$\sqrt{x^2+3x}+\sqrt{x^2-2x}+ax+b=(a+2)x+b+\frac12+\mathcal O(x^{-1})$$

and if you want this to approach $3$, you'll need

$$a+2=0\\b+\frac12=3$$

Comment: If you don't like using the binomial formula on square roots, you can note that, for instance, $\sqrt{x^2+3x}=\sqrt{(x+\frac32)^2-\frac94}$, where as $x$ increases, the $\frac94$ term will matter less and less. Similarly for the other square root. You then get the same result as above.

Comment: @Arthur Another good way of doing it.